# Does corpus linguistics research confirm/disconfirm Bolinger principle?

Tags: grammar, corpora

I remember learning about Bolinger's principle (basically, when there is a verb complement situation like "I like [verb complement]" or "I want to [verb complement]", gerunds are preferred to express completed/repeated actions and infinitives to express actions that have not yet been completed or taken; so "I like swimming" vs. "I want to swim") in grad school back in the 90s. I was wondering if corpus linguistics research has provided evidence to either confirm or disconfirm this principle. Thanks!